# Maven Multi-web application with shared modules

Tags: java, maven, web, modular-design

I have multi module web application:

```
Parent
|_common
|_dao
|_service
|_web (war)
```

And i want to create a new project that contains only scheduled tasks, but it depends on the modules above (except the web module).

I have create a new web module in the same parent project, the compilation maven is fine and it generate two war files after `build success` ... Also everything is fine in eclipse and i can see all my `dependencies`. But when i deploy the war on tomcat i get `ClassNotFoundException` from "`common module`" in both war modules and also on eclipse i had the same exception.

I hope you understand what i want to do

Comment: Typically, two web applications (wars) deployed to the same container cannot see each other unless you have specifically configured the container to do so.  Alternatively, you can package them into a single EAR, in which case they should share the same root classloader.  Check the classloader docs for apache tomcat: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Comment: Nothing prevents you from making the second `war` another module of the same `Parent` project. As long as it doesn't depend on what it doesn't need...

Comment: (1) Did you declare the dependency of the `web` modules on the `common` module in their respective POM? (2) Is the JAR built from the `common` module present in the WAR's `WEB-INF/lib`?